# Getting discord.py to talk using tts

Tags: python, discord.py, text-to-speech, voice

How would I get a my bot to use /tts in a vc?
Here is the code that I have so far. It is a loop of one word and I want to use tts in the voice channel I am in.

```py
@client.command()
async def start(ctx):
    global start_channel
    start_channel = ctx.channel.id
    reminder.start()
    await ctx.send('Bot has Started')


@tasks.loop(minutes=10)
async def reminder():
    channel = client.get_channel(int(start_channel))
    await channel.send('/tts Honk!')


@client.command()
async def stop(ctx):
    reminder.cancel()
    await ctx.send('Bot has stopped')

@client.command()
async def join(ctx):
  if ctx.author.voice is None:
    await ctx.send("You're not in a voice channel")
  voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
  if ctx.voice_client is None:
    await voice_channel.connect()
  else:
    await ctx.voice_channel.move_to(voice_channel)
```

Answer (score -1):

add tts as = True to allow it use tts commands through discord

```py
@tasks.loop(minutes=10)
async def reminder():
    channel = client.get_channel(int(start_channel))
    await channel.send('Honk!', tts=True)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).